# bash - getting line by line - error caused by pipe?

Tags: bash

i was trying to read file servers.txt and ping every line in it. 
it contains server on each line.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
output="pingtest.txt"
for line in < cat "servers.txt"
do 
ping $line >> "$output" 2>&1
done
```

But the script simply does not work, because of '<' on line 4.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: A general tip: checking your shell code at http://shellcheck.net usually helps.

Comment: @mklement0 That page is **Great**!. I'm going to develop a plugin for eclipse, integrating it with ShellEd. Another thing for wasting my time. Thank you!

Comment: @rpax: Great idea. While you're at it, how about a Sublime Text package? :)

Comment: @mklement0  Better idea, it's easier. Thanks!

Comment: @mklement0 I've been about to reinvent the wheel. https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-shellcheck .

Comment: @rpax: Thanks for that - it's an ST *3* package (I was looking in ST *2*, where it's NOT available).

Answer (score 3):

A for loop loops over what is essentially positional parameters. It does not read from standard input. `read` reads from standard input.

You want

```
while read line; do
  …
done < "servers.txt"
```

This is [the very first](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) BASH FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick with a for loop you could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
output="pingtest.txt"
for line in `cat servers.txt`
do 
    ping -c 1 -W 1 ${line} >> ${output} 2>&1
done
```

Also, you will want to provide a count and timeout for the ping command.

c : is the amount of times you would like to ping the server

W : is the amount of time to wait for the server to respond

Comment: While parsing command output with `for` will likely work in this specific case, it's generally a bad idea, because word splitting and pathname expansion occur; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs (talks about parsing `ls` output specifically, but it applies generally). Also, `bash` has deprecated the backtick syntax (`\`...\``) for command substitution in favor of the more flexible `$(...)`.